# Using JavaFX api from jfrt.jar in non JavaFX applications

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

Is it possible to use code which is not related to special javafx features in non JavaFX application?
My application builds on top of JavaSE 8. That means than the javafx runtime and the apis are included in any way.
Can i use the property framework of javafx from package javafx.beans located in the jfxrt.jar?
Is it neccesarry to run this code in the special java fx runtime?

Thanks in advance and best regards
Sebastian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't tried, but my *guess* is that you can use the following packages without starting the JavaFX platform:

- javafx.bean.*
- javafx.collections.*
- javafx.util.*

The question is if you really want to clutter non-GUI code with code from a GUI framework and thus create a dependency to JavaFX.

Personally, I still hope that Java will get some language level properties someday, hopefully with binding support.

Comment: I have tried, and that is correct (as of the current implementation). I have used JavaFX properties in server-side beans, with JPA annotations mapping them to database entities, etc (though javafx.collections creates issues for some ORMs). Your comments about dependencies are pertinent though, and while there's no obvious reason why these would require the FX toolkit to be running, there's no stated guarantee this would not be the case in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You are **free** to use them without any special JavaFX bootstrap code, ...